# How does Apple Watch decide whether to give you a Stand Up reminder or not?

Tags: apple-watch, health.app

I appreciate the "Time to stand" reminders that the Apple Watch provides ten minutes before the full hour. My assumption would be that these reminders pop up whenever I have not yet stood for at least one minute since the last full hour.

But this is not the case. I can sometimes sit for three hours in a row without getting any reminder (and it's not just me who indeed sat at my desk during the entire three hours, but also the watch has not registered any stand hours during this period. So it "knows" what's going on.

At first, I assumed that it might only issue those reminders later in the day when I am at risk of missing my stand-up goal for the day, but this is clearly not the case, since it also skips reminders in the evening, even when they would really make a difference (e.g. when I need to stand every hour until midnight in order to meet the goal).

So what is the pattern/logic? Or is it just random? Or is it indeed programmed to always remind at fifty minutes over the hour if no standing minute has yet been registered and it simply fails in doing so?